# Minecraft 1.20.1 resource pack texture atlas problem

Tags: json, minecraft

I am staff for a server and I am making a resource pack for it. I have been making a custom texture/model for an item with Blockbench and I have gotten everything set up. I got up to the point where the model was showing, but the texture for that model was not and was instead completely black. So I now have to add it to the texture atlas. I tried to do this by adding it to the blocks.json atlas but then this error **(Not a JSON object: null)** came up in the log, so I have no idea what to do as this has basically stumped me. I have no idea what atlas to put it in and if there is anything else I need to do.

I have attached the resource pack in a zip file if you wish to look at it. It is for version 1.20.1 btw
https://mega.nz/file/YCNCCYxA#xUcfN_CYF-X8mgaMa-atT0lHUvaHmeHmyVnG2h-wQZk

````
Failed to parse atlas definition minecraft:atlases/blocks.json in pack file/Site-19
java.lang.RuntimeException: Not a JSON object: null
    at com.mojang.serialization.DataResult.lambda$getOrThrow$5(DataResult.java:101)
    at com.mojang.datafixers.util.Either$Right.map(Either.java:99)
    at com.mojang.serialization.DataResult.getOrThrow(DataResult.java:93)
    at fuy.a(SourceFile:75)
    at fuq.a(SourceFile:113)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1768)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1760)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
23:37:25.052
Missing textures in model minecraft:brick#inventory:
    minecraft:textures/atlas/blocks.png:minecraft:custom/scp_500
    enter code here```
````

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma after the } on line 7.